# Criteria in NHibernate for "not in" or "not exists"

Tags: c#, .net, database, nhibernate

I am trying to create criteria in  NHibernate for the following statement:

```
SELECT *
  FROM InventoryItems
  where id not in (select inventory_id from InventoryItemCategories where Category_Id = 'EB0DA6DE-DC18-4306-9EF7-E506463555A9')
```

or i assume that this one is even better

```
SELECT *
  FROM InventoryItems
  where id not exists (select inventory_id from InventoryItemCategories where Category_Id = 'EB0DA6DE-DC18-4306-9EF7-E506463555A9')
```

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
 var criteria = Session.CreateCriteria<InventoryItem>()
      .Add(Subqueries.WhereNotExists(("id"), DetachedCriteria.For<InventoryItemCategories>()
       .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Category_id",inventoryCategoryId))));
```

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you relate your two entities, it will be easier

```
public class InventoryItem
{
    public virtual object Id{get;set;}
    public virtual IList<InventoryItemCategory> InventoryItemCategories{get;set;}
}
public class InventoryItemCategoriy
{
    public virtual InventoryItem InventoryItem{get;set;}
}
public class InventoryItemMap : ClassMap<InventoryItem>
{
    public InventoryItem()
    {
        Id(x=>x.Id);
        HasMany(x=>x.InventoryItemCategories).KeyColumn("Inventory_id");
    }
}
public class InventoryItemCategoryMap:ClassMap<InventoryItemCategory>
{
    public InventoryItemCategory()
    {
        References(x=>x.InventoryItem).Column("Id");
    }
}
```

And your query would be like as follows

```
session.Query<InventoryItem>().Where(x=>!x.InventoryItemCategories.Any(c=>c.Id=="EB0DA6DE-DC18-4306-9EF7-E506463555A9")).ToList();
```

Comment: It is not what i end up using but it also solved the problem. I end it up wrapping my sql string in NH and it was fine

Comment: Yes, there are lots of ways to resolve such issues in nhibernate, only you can decide which one is the most appropriate depending on your case. I think relating such entities would be more object oriented, reusable, maintainable, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Subqueries, or the not restriction, such as:

```
var subqueryFoodsWithCancerogenousSubstances = 
    DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(FoodCancerSubst))
            .SetProjection(Projections.Property("FoodId"));

ICriteria noCancerFood =
    session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Food))
    .Add(Subqueries.NotIn(subqueryFoodsWithCancerogenousSubstances))
    // check ID, else use PropertyNotIn(...)
```

or when using the IN clause for a disjunct values list, which doesn't have NotIn:

```
    .Add(Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.In("Id", cancerogenousFoodIdsList)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do it like this:

```
criteria.Add(Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.In ("id", detachedCrit));
```

Answer (score -1):

`IN` will generally map to a `Contains` call, in which you just reverse the parameters:

```
var subquery = context.InventoryItemCategories
    .Where(category => category.Category_Id == 
        'EB0DA6DE-DC18-4306-9EF7-E506463555A9')
    .Select(category => category.inventory_id);

var query = context.InventoryItems.Where(item => !subquery.Contains(item.id));
```

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote is for what appears to be an Entity Framework LINQ answer on an NHibernate Criteria question.  Different ORMs, different query syntaxes.  Criteria is from before the days of LINQ expressions.  It uses magic strings instead.